# Does pyspark support the graphx module

Tags: pyspark

From the API documentayion of he python language for spark , I can not find any thing for graphx, does it mean it is not supported yet, will it be support if it is not now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [graphframes](https://graphframes.github.io/user-guide.html) which supports both python and scala API. It is a dataframe version of graph RDDs and faster than graphX.